# Error exporting ggplot map to KML

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, gis, kml

I wonder if anyone has a fix for a GIS conversion (Thanks in advance for your invaluable advice on other questions, too). I am trying to export a choropleth map from R to KML format to place in a google map. I have to make a lot of these maps, so was hoping R would be an faster place to process them than ArcGIS (though if you have a tip there, too, that's helpful; I'm a modest user of both). I was able to cobble together a nice ggplot choropleth (following and thanks to [this](http://spatial.ly/2013/12/introduction-spatial-data-ggplot2/)) , but when I go to export to KML it gives the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"gg"’
```

Here, I'm trying to plot different values of "emanp" over the polygon "wards." Here's my code.

```
library(rworldmap)
library(foreign)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(shapefiles)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(plotKML)

#read in attributes
mayor2015<-read.dta("WardsMayor2015.dta")
#read in spatial data
wardmap<-readOGR("WARDS_2015.shp", layer="WARDS_2015")

#merge attributes and spatial
wardmap@data= data.frame(wardmap@data, mayor2015[match(wardmap@data[,"WARD"], mayor2015[,"WARD"]),])
    #fortify spatial
wardmap.f<-fortify(wardmap, region="WARD")
wardmap.f <- merge(wardmap.f, wardmap@data, by.x = "id", by.y="WARD")
#Map it
Map <- ggplot(wardmap.f, is.projected=TRUE, aes(long, lat, group=group, fill      =emanp15)) + geom_polygon() + 
    coord_equal() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = "%") + 
    ggtitle("Support")
Map + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black")
```

All seems to work through the ggplot command. When I use writeOGR, it gives the error above about inherited method.

```
#export to KML
writeOGR(Map, layer="ChiWards.kml", driver="KML", dataset_options=c("NameField=WARD"))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"gg"’
```

Same if I use writeOGR on the non-fortified data. Do I need to junk the ggplot, or do I have a bad projection setup, or am I just putting together too many different sources?

Here's the info on the spatial data "wardmap"

```
    > summary(wardmap)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
      min     max
x 1091131 1205198
y 1813892 1951669
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+proj=tmerc +lat_0=36.66666666666666 +lon_0=-88.33333333333333
+k=0.9999749999999999 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
+ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0]
```

Comment: I'm afraid ggplot2 produces a "grob", not something the spatial tools in R are going to be able to convert. If you do a `ggplot_build` you'll get a list structure that will have the data for the polygons (in a data frame) that you can convert into `SpatialPolygons` and then convert to KML.

Answer (score 0):

It has been three years since this question posted, but I thought I would share my thoughts. You may convert a `ggplot` to a `raster` object as follows:

1. Save the `ggplot` plot into an image file of any format (I would use `tiff`) using `ggsave`
2. Create a `raster` object for the saved image using `raster` (or `stack` for colored images)

The implementation of the above is as follows:

```
# You may need to remove the margins from the plot
Map <- Map + 
  theme(    
        axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "null"),
        legend.position = 'none'
       ) +
       labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)

# Save the plot
ggsave(plot=Map, "my_ggplot.tiff", device = "tiff")

# Create a StackedRaster object from the saved plot
rasterMap <- stack("my_ggplot.tiff")

# Get the GeoSpatial Components
lat_long <- ggplot_build(Map)$layout$panel_params[[1]][c("x.range","y.range")] 

# Supply GeoSpatial  data to the StackedRaster 
extent(rasterMap) <- c(lat_long$x.range,lat_long$y.range)
projection(rasterMap) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# Create the KML
writeOGR(rasterMap, layer="ChiWards.kml", driver="KML", dataset_options=c("NameField=WARD"))
```

Hope it helps.